# The type or namespace name 'Adult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have 3 files

Classexample.cs

```
class Human {
  
    protected string name;
    protected float height;
    protected int age;
   
    public string Name{
        get {
            //Debug.Log("Accessor Name get");
            return name;
        }
        set {
            //Debug.Log("Accessor Name set");
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public float Height{
        get {
            //Debug.Log("Accessor Height get");
            return height;
        }
        set {
            //Debug.Log("Accessor Height set");
            height = value;
        }
    }
    public int Age{
        get {
            //Debug.Log("Accessor Height get");
            return age;
        }
        set {
            //Debug.Log("Accessor Height set");
            age = value;
        }
    }

    public string getName(){
        Debug.Log("getName : " + name);
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(string val){
        Debug.Log("setName to val : " + val);
        name = val;
    }

    public Human(){}
    public Human(string _name, float _height, int _age){
        name = _name;
        height = _height;
        age = _age;
    }
    public void Eat(){
        Debug.Log("Eat_class Huuman");
    }
    public void Walk(){
        Debug.Log("Walk_class Huuman");
    }
    public void Sleep(){
        Debug.Log("Sleep_class Huuman");
    }
    
}
```

And InheritanceExample.cs

```
class Adult : Human {
        public int year;
        public Adult(){}

        public Adult(string _name, float _height, int _age) : base(_name, _height, _age){
            Debug.Log("Adult_Human Constructor");
        }

        public void printName(){
            Debug.Log(Name);
        }

        public int GetBaseAge(){
            return base.age;
        }

        public void Talk(){
            Debug.Log("class Adult Talk");
        }
    }
```

Lastly, TypeConversionExample.cs

```
Human jina = new Adult();
Adult jina = (Adult)jina;
//And here is the error part
```

The weird things is at first it was not error but I was busy so I stopped it for while and doing again now has the error

The type or namespace name 'Adult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)

like this.

I can not find why.. Wht did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't say what development environment (IDE) you're using, but if this worked before and now doesn't, and you haven't made any changes, then it's probably an IDE issue. I see this regularly with Visual Studio especially when switching repository branches. I suggest restarting your IDE, then doing a full clean and rebuild. If it still doesn't work, try clearing your IDE caches.

Comment: *Wht did I do wrong?* - used different namespaces, probably

Comment: Also, you cannot declare variables using the same name as an already declared variable `Human jina = ...
Adult jina = ...`

Comment: @NeilT You were right. I was using VSC in Unity. And it was issue with Unity problem that was the issue of file path, and scope issue of the class of the file.